# How to recognize which virtual environment is being used

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

Suppose I have logged in through `ssh`to a given Linux machine, knowing nothing about it.

How can I quickly check what virtual environment (VMWare, VirtualBox, LXC, etc., if any) is currently running on this machine?

Comment: You might use `dmesg` to view hardware type of, for example, the harddrive. Try `dmesg|egrep -i 'vmware|vbox'`

Comment: What do you want to know, that you did log into a VM client and which it is (which VM is ssh running in)? Or that you logged into a server and what VM has been started on it (which is the literal meaning of "what cultural environment is currently running **on**" this machine)?

Comment: I want to know which VM is ssh working in.

Answer (score 2):

If you're logging into a Virtual Machine, some of the hardware listed should be related to that Virtual Machine. Using a command like `dmidecode | grep VMware` should let you see if you're logged into a VM from VMware.

If you're not sure about what VM are you looking for, you could use just `dmidecode | head -n 40` just to take a look at the system manufacturer, which should be a VM name if the system is running on one.

Answer (score 2):

I like [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/virt-what.txt), which encapsulates a lot of this in an easy interface:

```
# virt-what    # VMware
vmware

# virt-what    # KVM/Qemu (libvirt)
kvm

# virt-what    # A real physical server

# virt-what    # VirtualBox
virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to test it.

1) `dmesg |grep -i hypervisor detected` ==> `Hypervisor detected: VMware`

2) `dmidecode -s system-product-name` ==> `VMware Virtual Platform`

These should work on most of the linux kernels